# Java regex patterns conjunction pattern

Tags: java, regex

Is there any way to get `Pattern` that will be a conjunction of two another, such that any `String` will match it if in matches two another both?

---

Some math:

> *S* — set of strings
> *P* — set of patterns (where each pattern has one or more string representation (e.g. “[0-9]” and “\d” are the same pattern))
>
> *Sᵢ* — subset of strings (*Sᵢ ⊂ S*) that match pᵢ pattern (where instead of i could be any index).
> In equation form: “*Sᵢ = {s | s ∈ S, s matches pᵢ, pᵢ ∈ P}*” — that meas: “*Sᵢ* is a set of elements that are strings and match *pᵢ* pattern”.
> Or another notation: “*Sᵢ ⊂ S, ∀pᵢ ∈ P ∀s ∈ S (s matches pᵢ ≡ s ∈ Sᵢ)*” — that meas: “*Sᵢ* is subset of strings and any string is element of *Sᵢ* if it matches *pᵢ* pattern”.
>
> Let's define conjunction of patterns: “*p₁ ∧ p₂ = p₃ ≡ S₁ ∩ S₂ = S₃*” — that means: “Set of strings that match conjunction of patterns *p₁* and *p₂* is intersection of sets of strings that match *p₁* pattern and that match *p₂* pattern”.

Comment: use `(?=foo)(?=bar).*`

Comment: @Doorknob What is `.*` for? Will this equation be correct: `Pattern.compile("(?=" + p1.pattern() + ")(?=" + p2.pattern() + ").*")`?

Comment: @Doorknob: The idea is good but is not correct. Check patterns `a.*`, `.*b` and string `abacus`.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you want *exact* matches (that is, `tomato` does not match `omat`), then you need to wrap each `p_i` between `(?=^(?:` and `)$)`, then join them.

If you want *inexact* matches (`tomato` does match `omat`), then you need to wrap each `p_i` between `(?=.*?(?:` and `))`, then join them. Note that in this case, there is the potential for catastrophic backtracking.

In both cases, you can add `.*` after joining if you want to eat the word (remember, lookaheads match the empty string).

**Explanation**

In the exact case, the outside is wrapped in a lookahead so that no characters are eaten. Inside are anchors `^` and `$` (this provides the exactness) surrounding a non-capturing group. The non-capturing group is so if you have an or expression at the upper level in one of `p_i`, the anchors apply to the entire group rather than to the first expression.

The inexact case is exactly the same, except instead of anchoring, we eat characters until we get to the match position.

You can see a detailed example on [www.debuggex.com](http://www.debuggex.com/?re=%28?=%5E%28?%3aa.%2aa%29%24%29%28?=%5E%28?%3a.%2afalfa%29%29.%2a&flags=&str=alfalfa).

Comment: If you're just checking a match, you can eliminate the trailing `.*`  Additionally, I'd add a starting anchor, and use lazy matching for a little efficiency uptick:  `^(?=.*?(?:p1))(?=.*?(?:p2))`

Comment: It is better to use `\A` and `\z` instead of `^` and `$`.

Comment: My final result for exact matching is `\A(?=p1\z)(?=p2\z).*` but backreferences within `p2` should be recounted.

Comment: @FrankieTheKneeMan, your pattern is incorrect. Try p1=`a.`, p2=`.b`: string `acb` will match your pattern but shouldn't (p1∧p2=`ab`).

Comment: @Errandir Not according to your original description of the problem, no.  It's very natural to assume that, but your description was: `p₁ ∧ p₂ = p₃ ≡ S₁ ∩ S₂ = S₃`.  `"acb"` matches both those regular expressions.  The case you're thinking of is p1 = `^a.$`, p2 = `^.b$`, in which case the intersection is `^ab$`, but my regular expression still works (albeit much less efficiently).

Comment: @FrankieTheKneeMan `"acb".matches("a.")` returns false.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#matches()  That's because `.matches()` attempts to match the entire string.  Essentially, it prepends the `^` and appends the `$` to the Regular expression.  If you want to match that behaviour, then use `"abc".matches("(?=p1$)(?=p2$).*")` - as you basically discovered.  Though, the problem is backreferences will begin to fail.

Comment: @F As you can see, `S` conforms to `s.matches(p)`. But pattern, that is result of conjunction, supposed to be used not only for exact matches.

Comment: @Sergiu Toarca: Why two lookaheads and not something like `\A(?=p1\z)p2\z`? It's asymmetric but simpler.

Answer (score 1):

```
private static String combineRE(String p1, String p2){
    int groups1 = 0, groups2=0;
    StringBuilder newP = new StringBuilder("(?=");
    newP.append(p1);
    newP.append("$)(?=");

    Pattern capturingGroup = Pattern.compile("(?<!\\\\)(\\\\\\\\)*\\((?!\\?)");
    Matcher m = capturingGroup.matcher(p1);
    while(m.find()) groups1 ++;

    m = capturingGroup.matcher(p2);

    while(m.find()) groups2 ++;
    String new2 = p2;

    for(int i=1; i<=groups2; i++)
        new2 = new2.replaceAll("(?<!\\\\)\\\\"+i, "\\\\" + (i+groups1));

    newP.append(new2);
    newP.append("$).*");
    return newP.toString();
}
```

This function uses the basic structure `(?=p1$)(?=p2$).*`, while recounting the numbered backreferences int the second pattern.  It uses a regular expression to count the number of capturing group openers (unescaped `(`s not followed by a `?`) in each pattern, then updates the backrefences in the second pattern before placing it in the resultant pattern.  I've set up a testing environment with ideone:  Please, add all the test cases you can think of, but I think this answers your question.

http://ideone.com/Wm8cRc

Round 2:

There's no good way to generate a Pattern that will `find()` a substring to match two patterns.  I toyed briefly with `(?=p1(?<p2)).*(?<(?=p1)p2)` and other such nonsense before giving up and writing, instead, an algorithm.  First, I slightly modified my CombineRE from before:

```
private static String combineRE(String p1, String p2, boolean anchors){
    int groups1 = 0, groups2=0;
    StringBuilder newP = new StringBuilder((anchors)?"^(?=":"(?=");
    newP.append(p1);
    if (anchors) newP.append('$');
    newP.append(")(?=");

    Pattern capturingGroup = Pattern.compile("(?<!\\\\)(\\\\\\\\)*\\((?!\\?)");
    Matcher m = capturingGroup.matcher(p1);
    while(m.find()) groups1 ++;

    m = capturingGroup.matcher(p2);

    while(m.find()) groups2 ++;
    String new2 = p2;

    for(int i=1; i<=groups2; i++)
        new2 = new2.replaceAll("(?<!\\\\)\\\\"+i, "\\\\" + (i+groups1));

    newP.append(new2);
    if (anchors) newP.append('$');
    newP.append(')');
    if (anchors) newP.append(".*");
    return newP.toString();
}
```

You'll see that it now supports optional anchors.  I used this functionality in my new function:

```
private static String[] findAllCombinedRE(String p1, String p2, String haystack, boolean overlap){
    ArrayList<String> toReturn = new ArrayList<String>();
    Pattern pCombo = Pattern.compile(combineRE(p1,p2, false));
    String pComboMatch = combineRE(p1,p2, true);
    Matcher m = pCombo.matcher(haystack);
    int s = 0;
    while (m.find(s)){
        String match = haystack.substring(m.start());
        s = m.start()+1;
        for (int i=match.length(); i>0; i--){
            String sMatch = match.substring(0,i);
            if (Pattern.matches(pComboMatch, sMatch)){
                toReturn.add(sMatch);
                /**
                 *  Note that at this point we can caluclute match
                 *  object like Information:
                 *  
                 *  group() = sMatch;
                 *  start() = m.start();
                 *  end() = m.start() + i;
                 *  
                 *  If it so suited us, we could pass this information
                 *  back in a wrapped object.
                 */
                if (!overlap){
                    s = m.start()+i;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return toReturn.toArray(new String[]{});
}
```

It uses an anchor free version of the two Regular Expressions to find all strings that might match, then chops off one letter at a time until the string matches the anchored version.  It also includes a boolean to control for overlapping matches.

http://ideone.com/CBoBN5  Works pretty well.

Comment: You really can't switch back and forth like this.  First you asked for `match()`, now you're asking to `find()` the largest substring that `match()`es.  I'm sorry, you're not going to be able to do that in a single regular expression.  The best you can do is take two regular expressions, and use the second one to try to `match()` each one the first one `find()`s.

Comment: Unfortunately seems to be so. There is `|` logical operator but no `&` in regular expressions…

Comment: @Errandir - Your original question having been answered (in the negative, I'm afraid), I did find a way to do it algorithmically.